# How to evenly spilt an array of strings into groups

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, sorting

**I am coding an app that the user will input chores and cleaners. Then the data gets sorted. The chores should be evenly shuffled between the cleaners.**

```
//this extension divides an array into chunks based on the number in the .chunked(by:)

var cleaners: [String] = ["person1", "person2"]


var chores: [String] = ["dishes", "laundry", "sweep patio", "dust", "trash","bathroom"]


var choresSorted = chores.chunked(by: cleaners.count)


extension Collection {

    func chunked(by distance: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        precondition(distance > 0, "distance must be greater than 0") // prevents infinite loop

        var index = startIndex
        let iterator: AnyIterator<Array<Element>> = AnyIterator({
            let newIndex = self.index(index, offsetBy: distance, limitedBy: self.endIndex) ?? self.endIndex
            defer { index = newIndex }
            let range = index ..< newIndex
            return index != self.endIndex ? Array(self[range]) : nil
        })

        return Array(iterator)
    }


print as [["dishes", "laundry"], ["sweep patio", "dust"], ["trash","bathroom"]]
```

So the problem is the chores are being grouped into 2s because there are 2 cleaners, I want to be able to sort them into 2 groups of 3 aka

```
print as [["dishes", "laundry", "sweep patio"], ["dust", "trash","bathroom"]]
```

PS I do not need to know how to shuffle them I already know how ill just use

```
chores.shuffle()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're chuncking your array into `cleaners.count` which is 2 in the example case. What you're looking for is the number of chores divided by the number of cleaners rounded into an integer value as below:

```
var choresSorted = chores.chunked(by: floor(chores.count / cleaners.count))
```

Also your extension code gave me cancer. Here's a cleaner implementation:

```
var cleaners: [String] = ["person1", "person2"]
var chores: [String] = ["dishes", "laundry", "sweep patio", "dust", "trash","bathroom"]

chores.shuffle()
var choresSorted = chores.chunked(by: floor(chores.count / cleaners.count))

extension Array {
    func chunked(into size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        return stride(from: 0, to: count, by: size).map {
            Array(self[$0 ..< Swift.min($0 + size, count)])
        }
    }
}
```

[Extension code source](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-split-an-array-into-chunks)

*Note: for `chorse.count` values that are not modulo `cleaners.count` (doesn't divide into a round number) you can also check out the behavior of `ceil` instead of `floor` or simply `round`.*

Comment: Thanks this worked for the most part, my extension was because it was useful in a previous app I made, and when I used yours it errored out.

Comment: There is no point in using floor() on an integer division since the result is an integer

Comment: that's why I decided to keep it the same, also for the note, ill just use an alert asking the user if they want to choose who gets the extra chore or if they want to randomly add it to someone